# This in class method vs arrow function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, scope

Good day

I recently ran into a strange situation where my `this` value in on a member function of a class is undefined. I know there are a lot of questions relating undefined `this` contexts, but I can't find any explanation of this issue. I would love to know why it happens. In this examples, why does the arrow function implementation of the `setModified` function keep its this context, but the function on the class does not.

This example breaks in the `setModified` function on the block class

```
class point {
    constructor(x, y) {
        this._x = x || 0;
        this._changeEvents = [];
    }

    set changeEvent(eventFunction) {
        this._changeEvents.push(eventFunction);
    }

    set x(value) {
        this._x = value;
        this.runChangeEvent();
    }

    set y(value) {
        this._y = value;
        this.runChangeEvent();
    }

    get x() {
        return this._x;
    }

    get y() {
        return this._y;
    }

    runChangeEvent() {
        this._changeEvents.forEach(event => event(this));
    }
}

class renderItem {
    constructor(canvas) {
        this._canvas = canvas;
    }

    render(){

    }
}

class block extends renderItem {
     constructor(canvas) {
        super(canvas);
        this._modified = true;
        this._topLeft = new point(0, 0);
        this._topLeft.changeEvent = this.setModified;
    }

    //Using a method on the class as a callback, it breaks
    setModified(){
         this._modified = true;//breaks, this is undefined
         console.log(this);
     }

    //Sets
    set topLeft(value) { this._topLeft = value; }

    //Gets
    get topLeft() { return this._topLeft }
}
//Creates an instance of the block
const bl = new block(null);
bl.topLeft.x = 20;
```

But when you change `setModified` function to an arrow function (also on the class), it works:

```
class point {
    constructor(x, y) {
        this._x = x || 0;
        this._y = y || 0;
        this._changeEvents = [];
    }

    set changeEvent(eventFunction) {
        this._changeEvents.push(eventFunction);
    }

    set x(value) {
        this._x = value;
        this.runChangeEvent();
    }

    set y(value) {
        this._y = value;
        this.runChangeEvent();
    }

    get x() {
        return this._x;
    }

    get y() {
        return this._y;
    }

    runChangeEvent() {
        this._changeEvents.forEach(event => event(this));
    }
}

class renderItem {
    constructor(canvas) {
        this._canvas = canvas;
    }

    render(){

    }
}

class block extends renderItem {
     constructor(canvas) {
        super(canvas);
        this._modified = true;
        //Using an arrow function on the class instance as a callback, it works
        this.setModified = () => {
            this._modified = true;//works
            console.log(this);
        };
        this._topLeft = new point(0, 0);
        this._topLeft.changeEvent = this.setModified;
    }

    //Sets
    set topLeft(value) { this._topLeft = value; }

    //Gets
    get topLeft() { return this._topLeft }
}
const bl = new block(null);
bl.topLeft.x = 20;
```

Why would the member function on the class lose the this context but not the arrow function?

Comment: `this._topLeft.changeEvent = this.setModified;` <= the `setModified` is being transfered to another variable, which does not have the other variable as a property.  `this._modified` exists.  `this._topLeft._modified` does not

Comment: Note there is a lot of code here not relevant to the specific problem. In future it would help if you scale it down to just a [mcve] and remove anything not relevant

Comment: Adding to @Taplar's comment, when reassigning, you can call `bind(this)` to prevent losing `this`. `this._topLeft.changeEvent = this.setModified.bind(this);`

Comment: Ohh... so the scope changes from the block class to the point class, because now it is a member function on the point class. I never thought of it that way. So the function will now have two scopes or closures depending from where it is called from. If I understand you correctly?

Comment: I re-created the problem. `this` does not bind to `this._topLeft`. It's actually `undefined`. From the book I reference in my answer, after trying to understand why default binding was occurring: `var bar = obj.foo;` then calling `bar()`  Even though `bar` appears to be a reference to `obj.foo`, in fact, it's really just another reference to `foo` itself. Moreover, the call-site is what matters, and the call-site is `bar()`, which is a plain, un-decorated call and thus the default binding applies. I updated my answer, let me know if I said anything wrong.

Comment: The above comment was to clarify it doesn't matter if `this._topLeft._modified` did exist, it'd still cause an error.

Comment: So, after changing the forEach loop to a for loop in the runChangeEvent function like
for (var i =0; i< this._changeEvents.length;i++){
  this._changeEvents[i]();
}
this was available. But this was the instance of the array, which would make sense because the function is now a member of the array.

Comment: Related: [How to access the correct `this` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484/218196)

Comment: @Diesel Thanks, you made it clear, very good answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> An arrow function expression is a syntactically compact alternative to
> a regular function expression, although without its own bindings to
> the this, arguments, super, or new.target keywords.

The scope of an arrow function is no different than a regular function, but as you can see above from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), they handle the binding of `this` different.

An arrow function does not create its own binding to `this`, in fact it inherits from the enclosing scope (which is the class). In the class, the `this._modified` exists.

> An arrow function does not have its own this. The this value of the
> enclosing lexical scope is used; arrow functions follow the normal
> variable lookup rules.

`this` is determined in the execution context, and as we've shown the arrow function works because `this` stays with the `this` of the enclosing scope. However with a normal function...

> In strict mode, however, if the value of this is not set when entering
> an execution context, it remains as undefined

If you `console.log(this)` before the error in your function you will see it is `undefined`. But why is it `undefined`? Read [here](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/1st-ed/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes/ch2.md) under the implicitly lost section. But basically default binding is applied when calling it as a plain, undecorated function reference, which it is from the assignment. And under strict mode, `this` will return `undefined` while not in the global scope.

Implicit binding doesn't occur in your case and `this` can be implicitly lost.

> One of the most common frustrations that this binding creates is when
> an implicitly bound function loses that binding, which usually means
> it falls back to the default binding, of either the global object or
> undefined, depending on strict mode.

If you change your call in `runChangeEvent()` to `event.call(this)` you will see that `this` is actually the `point`'s this (not what you want). If you call `this._topLeft.changeEvent = this.setModified.bind(this);` you will have the scope you want.

> Calling f.bind(someObject) creates a new function with the same body
> and scope as f, but where this occurs in the original function, in the
> new function it is permanently bound to the first argument of bind,
> regardless of how the function is being used.

Check out that link for more information and also I recommend this [online book](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/1st-ed/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes/ch2.md) referenced earlier.

Comment: I am aware that arrow functions inherit their "this". But in this example, both the arrow function and the member function on the class should have access to the same "this"?

Comment: How are you calling setModified?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-breeze-rxwod?file=/src/index.js I made a code sandbox. Both methods work on here. Which is why I ask.

Comment: I get it now. Haha, How did I not think of that. Your code sandbox together with @Taplar comment made it clear.. Thanks

Comment: @Philip I got curious about why `this` was undefined for you. I did some reading and tried to clarify my answer. This should help.